# Best way to analyse url paramaters for a single page within Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters

I'm trying to study real world usage of a search page in a website.  The search results page use URL parameters for its settings.  The parameters are very simple and straight forward, for example:

> www.domain.com/search?location=london&startDate=20/04/2016&endDate=23/04/201‌​6

Studying the raw logs on the web server of http access is what I really want to do but I can't as the logs have been disabled on this particular server.

However, as the site has been setup with Google Analytics for a while I assume there is a complete record of access to the search results page INCLUDING all the URL parameters.  From this I concluded it can't be too difficult to obtain a report from Analytics that shows all the access to this page and for me to then export the report so that I can obtain raw data on the url parameters used.

Yet I'm finding it difficult to find a report or option within Analytics that will let me do this.   Does anyone know of a way to focus on url parameters like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom report with `pageviews` as the metric and `page` as the dimension and set a filter for `page contains /search?`. This will give you the hits to each search result broken out by various combinations of URL parameters.

Here is a screenshot that might help.

[image: custom report setup]

You might want to set up `site-search` in the view settings and setting `location` as the search parameter. That way you can see reports like that much easier in the future.

Comment: Amazing @Verb Interactive, really great answer

Comment: Glad I could help.